# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3+n^2+1} \mathrm{e}^{-2n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Does the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3+n^2+1} \mathrm{e}^{-2n^2}
$$
converge?

The ratio test is inconclusive, so I think I must use the comparison test. But I couldn't find a series to use in this case. Any hint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What other tests do you know ... for when the ratio test fails?

Comment: What do you know about the relations between $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n,\, \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+1}$ and $e^x$?

Comment: The limit of both of the first sequences is $e^x$, but I couldnt find a way of applying this.

Comment: @GEdgar the general therm test and comparasion test (and alternanting series, but they are not the case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since 
$$
\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\mathcal{O}(x^5), \quad \lvert x\rvert<1,
$$
we have that
$$
\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)=\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{8}{3n^3}-\frac{4}{n^4}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-5}).
$$
In particular, using the Taylor expansion theorem, we obtain that the ${\mathcal O}(n^{-5})$
term is of the form $n^{-5}a_n$, whre $a_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Then we have that
$$
\log a_n=\log \left(\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n^3+n^2+1} \left(\frac{1}{e^2}\right)^{n^2}\right) \\
=(n^3+n^2+1)\left(\frac{2}{n}-\frac{2}{n^2}+\frac{8}{3n^3}-\frac{4}{n^4}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-5})\right)-2n^2\\=
\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3n}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-2})
$$
Hence $a_n=\mathrm{e}^{2/3+2/3n+{\mathcal O}(n^{-2})}\to\mathrm{e}^{2/3}$ and thus the series diverges.

Comment: Can you look at [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/947567/a-convergence-test-similar-to-gauss-test)?

Comment: I couldnt understand your calculation, sorry. Can you give me any material that explains it better?

Comment: @Giiovanna. See update.

Comment: Ok, you just made a series expansion, right?